# Viber API отправка сообщений

Tags: php, html, json, api, viber

Здравствуйте. Появилась идея сделать отправку сообщений в public account на Viber через сайт. На оф. сайте ничего толком не понятно как это реализовать. Сам аккаунт уже завел.
Например, простая форма: поле и кнопка. хочу при нажатии сделать отправку туда. Как это сделать? *(Гугл не помог)*

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Send to Viber">
</form>
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/321246/  и https://developers.viber.com/api/rest-bot-api/index.html

Comment: на офсайте, кстати, очень так даже подробно описано что и как. https://developers.viber.com

Comment: @labris, на хабре читал статью до этого, в коде было `require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");`, я не нашел файла этого на github

Comment: Странно, вот же он https://github.com/Bogdaan/viber-bot-php/blob/master/examples/setup.php

Comment: @labris, это setup.php а не autoload.php

Comment: Директория vendor и прочие файлы в ней создаются composer автоматически при установке пакета.

Comment: Скачайте пакет через composer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Вот пример моего кода:

```
class Viber
{
    private $url_api = "https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/";

    private $token = "";

    public function message_post
    (
        $from,          // ID администратора Public Account.
        array $sender,  // Данные отправителя.
        $text           // Текст.
    )
    {
        $data['from']   = $from;
        $data['sender'] = $sender;
        $data['type']   = 'text';
        $data['text']   = $text;
        return $this->call_api('post', $data);
    }

    private function call_api($method, $data)
    {
        $url = $this->url_api.$method;

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nX-Viber-Auth-Token: ".$this->token."\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode($data)
            )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return json_decode($response);
    }
}
$Viber = new Viber();
$Viber->message_post(
    '01234567890A=',
    [
        'name' => 'Admin', // Имя отправителя. Максимум символов 28.
        'avatar' => 'http://avatar.example.com' // Ссылка на аватарку. Максимальный размер 100кб.
    ],
    'Test'
);
```

Этот класс можно продолжить добавляя функции к каждому методу.

Comment: вроде как не стало public account. 
и токена логично нет. 

бота привязать на канал, как это делает телеграм то же нельзя(((

как нынче это делается?